# Rotating text in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is a better way to achieve the following result? I want to add the rotated labels, but I have to have the `\addplot[black] coordinates {...};` line in order for `\draw (axis cs:...` to work and produce the rotated labels. There is the obvious problem that the lines of the triangles are being traced twice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

%45-45-90
\begin{axis}[name=plot1,
x=4cm,y=4cm,clip=false,
hide x axis, hide y axis]
\addplot[black] coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,0)};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(0.9,0)(0.9,0.1)(1,0.1)};
\draw (axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:1,0) node[anchor=north, pos=0.5]{Adjacent};
\draw (axis cs:1,0)--(axis cs:1,1) node[anchor=north, rotate=90, pos=0.5]{Opposite};
\draw (axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:1,1) node[anchor=south, rotate=45, pos=0.5]{Hypotenuse};
\node at (axis cs:0.185,0.077) {\(\theta\)};
\end{axis}

%30-60-90
\begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(6em,0)$)},anchor=west,
x=4cm,y=4cm,clip=false,
hide x axis, hide y axis]
\addplot[black] coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,0.577)(0,0)};
\addplot[black] coordinates {(0.9,0)(0.9,0.1)(1,0.1)};
\draw (axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:1,0) node[anchor=north, pos=0.5]{Adjacent};
\draw (axis cs:1,0)--(axis cs:1,0.577) node[anchor=north, rotate=90, pos=0.5]{Opposite};
\draw (axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:1,0.577) node[anchor=south, rotate=30, pos=0.5]{Hypotenuse};
\node at (axis cs:0.193,0.052) {\(\theta\)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: name]

Comment: Why are you using `pgfplots` for this? The natural choice here is pure TikZ.

Comment: I have a number of other `pgfplots` diagrams in my document, and I want to use it throughout for the sake of homogeneity.

Comment: @Eridan pgfplots is built on TikZ and actually loads TikZ (so you can remove `\usepackage{tikz}` in your code). There is no homogeneity issue.

Comment: Thanks. I should also add that `pgfplots` is the only graphic-producing program I learned. I don't know how to use straight-up `tikz`.

Comment: \draw and \node are plain tikz, although (axis cs:...) is special to pgfplots.

Comment: node[above, midway,sloped]{hypoteneuse} will work for any angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axis` environment does not know its size, when `\addplot` is not used, and `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` must be given explicitly, e.g.:

```
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
```

But the bounding box is still not correct because of the nodes.

The doubling the lines can be avoided by using `\path` instead of `\draw` to place the nodes.

But I think it is easier to go without `axis`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%45-45-90
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=4cm, y=4cm,
]
  \draw[thin]
    (.9, 0) -- (.9, .1) -- (1, .1)
    (.25, 0) arc(0:45:.25)
    (22.5:.18) node {$\theta$}
  ;
  \draw[semithick]
    (0, 0) -- node[anchor=north] {Adjacent}
    (1, 0) -- node[anchor=north, sloped] {Opposite}
    (1, 1) -- node[anchor=south, sloped] {Hypothenuse}
    cycle
  ;

%30-60-90
\begin{scope}[shift={($(current bounding box.east |- 0, 0) + (6em, 0)$)}]
  \draw[thin]
    (.9, 0) -- (.9, .1) -- (1, .1)
    (.25, 0) arc(0:30:.25)
    (15:.18) node {$\theta$}
  ;
  \draw[semithick]
    (0, 0) -- node[anchor=north] {Adjacent}
    (1, 0) -- node[anchor=north, sloped] {Opposite}
    (1, {tan(30)}) -- node[anchor=south, sloped] {Hypothenuse}
    (0, 0) -- cycle
  ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Hints:**

- TikZ can calculate, e.g. instead of `0.577`, `{tan(30)}` can be given as part of the coordinate.
- `sloped` is simpler than specifying `rotate` with angle, see John Kormylo's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266474/rotating-text-in-pgfplots/266492#comment638615_266474).
- Connected line segments should not be separated by `\draw` with a single line.
  Then the line connections are quite bad. The lines should be given in a single `\draw` command and closed paths should be use `cycle`:

  ```
  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- cycle;
  ```

  Then the line joins are much better and can also be configured via option `line join`.
- The additional `(0, 0)` before `-- cycle` should not be necessary, but there seems to be a bug in connection with the shifted scope. Without, the node is misplaced to the right.

### Version with vertically centered drawings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%45-45-90
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=4cm, y=4cm,
  baseline=(current bounding box.center),
]
  \draw[thin]
    (.9, 0) -- (.9, .1) -- (1, .1)
    (.25, 0) arc(0:45:.25)
    (22.5:.18) node {$\theta$}
  ;
  \draw[semithick]
    (0, 0) -- node[anchor=north] {Adjacent}
    (1, 0) -- node[anchor=north, sloped] {Opposite}
    (1, 1) -- node[anchor=south, sloped] {Hypothenuse}
    cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{6em}%
%30-60-90
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=4cm, y=4cm,
  baseline=(current bounding box.center),
]
  \draw[thin]
    (.9, 0) -- (.9, .1) -- (1, .1)
    (.25, 0) arc(0:30:.25)
    (15:.18) node {$\theta$}
  ;
  \draw[semithick]
    (0, 0) -- node[anchor=north] {Adjacent}
    (1, 0) -- node[anchor=north, sloped] {Opposite}
    (1, {tan(30)}) -- node[anchor=south, sloped] {Hypothenuse}
    cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result vertically centered]

Answer (score 5):

`pgfplots` is meant for plotting. When you have to draw something, use the proper tool. Here it is `tikz` as suggested by Gonzalo. There is no loss of homogeneity and you don't have to load `tikz` as it is loaded by `pgfplots` itself. The code is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (3,3);
        \coordinate (C) at (3,0);
        \draw (A) -- node[above,sloped]{Hypotenuse} (B)
                    -- node[below,rotate=180,sloped] {Opposite} (C)
                    -- node[below] {Adjacent} (A);
        \path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = C--A--B};
        \draw ($(C)!3mm!(B)$) -| ($(C)!3mm!(A)$);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]